# Why do I get missing data rows when I run this virtual layer area query?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, area, virtual-layer

I have a shapefile of circles called circlesdixie. I have a polygon layer called FCC (the shp download link at https://www.fcc.gov/reports-research/maps/auction-904-updated-jun20-eligible-areas/. I'm creating a new virtual layer which calculated what percent of each polygon each circle covers: If a polygon is covered equally by two circles this new layer will have a row saying: `Circle 1 Polygon 1 50 Pct` and a row saying `Circle 2 Polygon 1 50 Pct`. That's what this does:

```
with circle_land_intersection as (
select c.name circlename, l.name landname, st_area(l.geometry) total_land_area,
    st_intersection(c.geometry,l.geometry) geometry
from circlesdixie c, FCC l
where st_intersects(c.geometry, l.geometry)
),
area_calc as (
select *, st_area(i.geometry) intersect_area
from circle_land_intersection i
)

select *, round(intersect_area/total_land_area*100) pct from area_calc;
```

This works on other polygon layers but when I run it on the FCC layer, I get a shapefile with a DBF of only one feature, even though 98 features correctly display on a map. The table says

> Features Total 98 Filtered 1.

It's strange.

Is there any way to fix this? Is it bad geometry or corrupt data?

Comment: When you run that you'll get a *Virtual Layer*, and when you export that *Virtual Layer*, you'll get a shapefile; what are the exact steps you take for saving that layer to shapefile? The table header suggests that you have a single feature marked via selection, have an active filter on the layer, or it is filtered by spatial bounds of the viewport. When exporting, make sure you export all features of that layer.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't remember applying any filters. I just right click and save as SHP. It's possible that I messed with something in settings recently and that could be whats causing it

Comment: The source file presented on the site has the wrong geometry (self-intersections, etc.)...

Comment: I tried using the "fix geometry" tool and it didn't help. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Change the original geodata must those producers who provide them, ie the user does not understand the order of geodata after the "its" correction can make them even more inaccurate, so it is necessary to notify the manufacturer of geodata about this problem! If the user needs these geodata for personal purposes, and he does not care about their correctness, it is possible to "fix" them, but this is already the process of geodata processing and analysis...

Comment: You can check the geodata for wrong geometry, for example by running ST_IsValid() and fix the wrong geometry, but this is a necessary and thankless job...